# Post Submission from frontend with custom field isn't working

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm working with submitting posts from fronted which has some custom fields. I used shortcode API to use the form in any page/post. The code should be found bellow. But after submitting the form, nothing happened and the form returns. I need your kind help.

```
<?php
//Shortcode API
function apl_video(){
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

?>
<form name="new_post" method="post" action="">

    <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr><td><label for="id_meta">Video Title</label></td><td><input id="post_title" tabindex="1" type="text" name="post_title"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td><label for="vid_wid">Video Width</label></td><td><input id="vid_wid" tabindex="2" type="text" name="vid_wid"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td><label for="vid_hei">Video Height</label></td><td><input id="vid_hei" tabindex="3" type="text" name="vid_hei"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td><label for="vid_ply">Autoplay</label></td><td><select tabindex="4" name="vid_ply" id="vid_ply">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>

        <tr><td><label for="vid_ski">Skin</label></td><td><select tabindex="5" name="vid_ski" id="vid_ski">
        <option value="player1">Player 1</option>
        <option value="player2">Player 2</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>


        <tr>
          <td><label for="vid_you">Youtube Video Link</label></td>
          <td><input id="vid_you" tabindex="6" type="text" name="vid_you"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="vid_mp4">MP4 Video Link</label></td>
          <td><input id="vid_mp4" tabindex="7" type="text" name="vid_mp4"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="vid_ogg">OGG Video Link</label></td>
          <td><input id="vid_hei" tabindex="8" type="text" name="vid_ogg"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="vid_web">WEBM Video Link</label></td>
          <td><input id="vid_hei" tabindex="9" type="text" name="vid_web"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="vid_pst">Poster Image Link</label></td>
          <td><input id="vid_hei" tabindex="10" type="text" name="vid_pst"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

            <td><input type="submit" value="Generate" name="submit"/></td>

        </tr>

    </table>



</form>

<?php }

else {
    $title      =   esc_attr($_POST['post_title']);
    $vid_wid    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_wid']);
    $vid_hei    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_hei']);
    $vid_ply    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_ply']);
    $vid_ski    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_ski']);
    $vid_you    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_you']);
    $vid_mp4    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_mp4']);
    $vid_web    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_web']);
    $vid_ogg    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_ogg']);
    $vid_pst    =   esc_attr($_POST['vid_pst']);


    global $user_ID;

    $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'video',
            'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_author'   => $user_ID,
    );

    //save the new post
    $pid    =   wp_insert_post($new_post);

    // Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
    do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post'); 

    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_wid', $vid_pst, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_hei', $vid_hei, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_ply', $vid_ply, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_ski', $vid_ski, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_you', $vid_you, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_ogg', $vid_ogg, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_web', $vid_web, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_mp4', $vid_mp4, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'vid_pst', $vid_pst, true);



    //Result
    echo 'Done';



        }
}


add_shortcode( 'wpvideogen', 'apl_video' );
```

Comment: Can you explain how this form submission works? Is it using wp_ajax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me as-is, assuming you actually have a `video` post type, however there are a couple of things you can correct-

1. shortcodes should `return` their value, otherwise you will see shortcode content appear before any post content, not where you actually placed the shortcode.
2. `do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');` is unnecessary, `wp_insert_post` already does that action within the function, so you're invoking it twice.

Comment: Thanks Milo but I just tried to get post id using `$pid    =   wp_insert_post($new_post);` and used `add_shortcode( 'wpvideogen', 'apl_video' );` to call the shortcode.
Please help me to recognize if I did any mistake.